# What causes the energy produced by the motion of molecules to manifest as heat?

Tags: energy

Why is **heat** the resulting form of energy when molecules are in motion? Is this just an intrinsic property or is there a deeper explanation as to what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

Heat is actually not the motion of molecules. That is called internal energy, specifically, internal kinetic energy. Internal potential energy is that associated with intermolecular forces.

Heat is actually one of two forms of energy transfer. It is due solely to a temperature difference between substances. The other form is work (mechanical energy transfer).

Heat *transfers* the kinetic energy of the molecules from a substance at higher temperature to the molecules of a substance at lower temperature. A good pictorial of the concept can be found here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your question stems from a common confusion about the meanings of "heat" and "temperature".

The *notion* of temperature comes from our skin's perception of warmth.  Careful science showed that our perception of high or low temperature correlates to the amount of *random molecular motion* in an object, whether it is solid, liquid, or gas.  Thermometers were invented to provide a consistent measurement of temperature, independent of our perception.

Further careful science showed that the amount of energy required to change the temperature of an object by a given amount depends on the composition of the object as well as the mass of the object.  The portion of internal energy comprising random molecular motion was termed "heat".  So, the term "heat" is just our name for the random-motion component of energy.   So, asking why heat is the result of (random) molecular motion, then, is a bit like asking why your username is JuliaW.

On the other hand, you may really be asking why we *perceive* increased random molecular motion as corresponding to a higher temperature.  But that question, too, is nearly unanswerable: it's akin to asking why we perceive a certain range of wavelengths as "red".  The fact that we have temperature sensors in our skin, though, *does* have an explanation but it's in the realm of evolutionary biology rather than hard physics: it's because it gave our ancestors a survival advantage.

Comment: yes the motion has to be random. There is laser cooling where the molecules are all made to flow in the same direction

Answer (score 0):

Heat is the flow of energy, not the energy of the molecules.

If there is a bunch of them in a region, with more energy than the average, energy tends to spread. Or because the molecules spread themselves or because they collide to others, exchanging energy.

Comment: Heat can flow, but it is not flow *per se*.  Consider a hot cube of iron wrapped with good insulation for example.  Nothing flows within the cube, but the cube contains a lot of heat.

Comment: @S. McGrew I would say a lot of internal energy. The cube of iron can be hot now due to heavy plastic deformation, without any heat flow.

Comment: Browsing through the various contradictory online definitions of "heat" and "internal energy", I can see why you use the terms the way you do.  It is legitimate.  But a typical definition of heat is like, "heat is energy that is transferred by conduction between two bodies of different temperature", right next to "heat is the transfer of internal energy between two bodies due to a temperature difference between them".  A lot of room for confusion there!